# User wait for some time

Tags: c#

I need to fix a problem and need some input. When I press `button1` my gui starts serial comm. I send some commands and receive some data. Once I press `button1` I am in the other thread (other than GUI thread) for 3-4 sec until data is fully transferred. What I want is a dialog box, pop up or some thing like that (showing a busy message) to appear in front of my gui when I press the `button1` and this pop closes automatically in the other thread in which serial communication is taking place when the whole data is transferred.

Some people suggested `BackgroundWorker` but I was not clear.

I also got a suggestion *" Use a winform, set its FormBorderStyle to FixedDialog. Make it small like a messagebox and drop a progressbar control on it. You can use the forms ShowDIalog at the beginning of your thread processing, and Close at the end. The progress bar Style can be set to continous for simplicity."*

**Any good explanation or an alternative easy way to do it considering my scenario** ?
I want to keep things simple

Answer (score 0):

You can set simple message using Label on your form or by using progress bar and update progress bar after few commands have been executed. if your set of commands have been initiated by user instruction then it fine. 
if you have to communicate with device and respond to device alerts then DataReceivedEvent of serialport in C# works fine. you can write your code their. this Event get fired when ever device transmit date to application and works in background.

Answer (score 0):

here is the logic:

> - show the popup box saying something, when user clicks on button1.
> - and while that, data transfer code should also be in the same thread.
> - and then write code for get a point when all the data will be transferred & @ that point make that dialog box disappear.

If you want any sample codes then please post your written code too, so that i can give a practical approached code to show you the logic.

hope you understand or better post your code.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually for this part I dont have any code yet. At the moment what I have is a simple a button with a associated click event in which I start serial comm. And as you know that c# has a receive function for serial comm which is a separate thread and thats where I want to close  the pop up.

Comment: Moreover, Can you please elaborate what sort of "popup box" u mean here (I cant use the messagebox, right?). Do I need to make a custom popup or what ?

Comment: You also can make your own costume control but by my view that's tough to make that kind of one control. and you definetly can use messagebox in this manner :

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("My message here");
Make sure the System.Windows.Forms assembly is referenced your project.

Answer (score 0):

A BackgroundWorker is indeed the best option. There is a very thorough HowTo right [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One Q, would back ground worker affect my current implementation ? If yes in what way ? as I would rather like to keep changes to my current code as minimum as possible

Comment: Yes, it would. However, you need a way of processing your stuff in the background, so any background worker will affect your implementation. Have a look at the code posted in the other answer using a thread or Task. The BackgroundWorker will take about as much work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state what version of .net you are running, so I'll provide both methods:

### .net 4:

```
void OnButton1Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var waitDailog = new frmWait();
    waitDialog.ShowDialog();

    var task = new Task(() = 
    {
        // Serial communitcation or whatever will take a long time here
    })
    .ContinueWith(result =>
    {
        waitDialog.Close();
    })
    .Start();
}
```

### .net 3:

```
private frmWait _waitDialog;

void OnButton1Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    _waitDailog = new frmWait();
    waitDialog.ShowDialog();

    var thread = new Thread(OnThread);
    thread.Start();
}

void OnThread()
{
    // Serial communitcation or whatever will take a long time here

    _waitDailog.Close();
}
```

In both cases the wait dialog is just a form, with some kind of animation and message to show waiting.

You might need some `Invoke()` on the closing of the wait form too, but I don't have a compiler close to hand to check.